# Cyclic dependency returns empty object in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have two React Native Components (Alpha and Beta) that navigate to one another; however, this produces a cyclic dependency and React Native doesn’t seem to handle those.

Requiring Beta in Alpha works fine, but requiring Alpha in Beta returns an empty object. An error is thrown when trying to push a route with an invalid component.

Can cyclic dependencies work in React Native? If not, how do I get around this?

### Code

index.ios.js

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var Alpha = require('./Alpha');

var {
    AppRegistry,
    NavigatorIOS,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} = React;

var ExampleProject = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigatorIOS
                style={styles.container}
                initialRoute={{
                    component: Alpha,
                    title: Alpha.title,
                    wrapperStyle: styles.wrapper
                }} />
        );
    },
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    wrapper: {
        paddingTop: 64
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('ExampleProject', () => ExampleProject);
```

Alpha.js

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Beta = require('./Beta');

var {
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableHighlight,
    View,
    Text
} = React;

var Alpha = React.createClass({
    statics: {
        title: 'Alpha'
    },

    goToBeta() {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            component: Beta,
            title: Beta.title,
            wrapperStyle: styles.wrapper
        });
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.linkWrap}
                    onPress={this.goToBeta}>
                    <Text>Go to Beta</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    linkWrap: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 30
    },
    wrapper: {
        paddingTop: 64
    }
});

module.exports = Alpha;
```

Beta.js

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Alpha = require('./Alpha');

var {
    StyleSheet,
    TouchableHighlight,
    View,
    Text
} = React;

var Beta = React.createClass({
    statics: {
        title: 'Beta'
    },

    goToAlpha() {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            component: Alpha,
            title: Alpha.title,
            wrapperStyle: styles.wrapper
        });
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <TouchableHighlight style={styles.linkWrap}
                    onPress={this.goToAlpha}>
                    <Text>Go to Alpha</Text>
                </TouchableHighlight>
            </View>
        );
    }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    linkWrap: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 30
    },
    wrapper: {
        paddingTop: 64
    }
});

module.exports = Beta;
```

Comment: Running into exactly the same problem. Maybe open an issue on GitHub because this looks like a fairly common use case.

Comment: Here is the issue that I opened: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3076

Answer (score 27):

This is a common problem with routing components. There are a couple of ways to approach this. In general, you want Alpha to avoid requiring Beta before Alpha has defined its exports and vice versa.

Fortunately, JavaScript's `import` and `export` keywords address this issue by lazily importing values using an intermediate object that acts as a level of indirection. A specific example is a lot easier to understand.

---

## With `import` and `export`

Use the `export` keyword to export Alpha and Beta from their respective files, and use the `import` keyword to import them:

```
// Alpha.js
import Beta from './Beta';

var Alpha = React.createClass({
    /* ... */
});
export default Alpha;
```

This works because at runtime, the `export` keyword creates an intermediate object (equivalent to `module.exports` in CommonJS) and assigns a property named `default` to it with the value of `Alpha`. So, the above `export` statement is conceptually similar to this:

```
module.exports.default = Alpha;
```

The files that import Alpha then get a reference to the intermediate object, not Alpha itself until `Alpha` is directly used. So this code here actually lazily accesses Alpha:

```
import Alpha from './Alpha';

var ExampleProject = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigatorIOS
                style={styles.container}
                initialRoute={{
                    component: Alpha,
                    title: Alpha.title,
                    wrapperStyle: styles.wrapper
                }}
            />
        );
    },
});
```

The lazy access is implemented by running code conceptually similar to this:

```
var AlphaExports = require('./Alpha');

var ExampleProject = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigatorIOS
                style={styles.container}
                initialRoute={{
                    component: AlphaExports.default,
                    title: AlphaExports.default.title,
                    wrapperStyle: styles.wrapper
                }}
            />
        );
    },
});
```

---

## With `require()`

Using CommonJS's `require`, you have some other options:

### Approach 1: Lazy Loading

Alpha and Beta don't need each other until the user navigates from one scene to the next. For the app to reach this state, Alpha must have defined its exports (that is, `module.exports = Alpha` must have run for your app to have rendered an Alpha component). So, when the user is navigating to the scene displaying Beta, it is safe for Beta to require Alpha and therefore it is safe to require Beta at this point in time.

```
// Alpha.js
var Alpha = React.createClass({
    goToBeta() {
        // Lazily require Beta, waiting until Alpha has been initialized
        var Beta = require('./Beta');

        this.props.navigator.push({
            component: Beta,
            title: Beta.title,
            wrapperStyle: styles.wrapper
        });
    }
});
```

Although it isn't necessary to do the same for Beta.js in this specific scenario because Alpha is the first component loaded, it's probably a good idea so that your components all handle dependency cycles the same way.

### Approach 2: Single Module

Another solution is to put Alpha and Beta in the same JS file to remove a cycle between modules. You would then export both components from the new mega-module.

```
// AlphaBeta.js
var Alpha = React.createClass({...});
var Beta = React.createClass({...});
exports.Alpha = Alpha;
exports.Beta = Beta;
```

To require it:

```
// index.js
var {Alpha, Beta} = require('./AlphaBeta');
```

Comment: I ran into this, and Approach 1: Lazy Loading worked for me. But I'm curious why this is necessary. Both modules declare an export via `module.exports = X`. Shouldn't that be enough? Thanks

Comment: Great answer @ide. Thanks. :)

Comment: this got me unstuck @ide. I would give you an after the fact bounty if I could. Instead...single upvote. Great explanation! Thanks for taking the time to write it.