# React Native error: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object

Tags: react-native

This is regarding react-native application android

I have *FirstScreen.js*

In that I have implemented navigation drawer. The content on navigation drawer changes on based of certain criteria
i have implemented:

```
var Logout= require('./Logout');
```

Now when  from *Logout.js* i try calling this *FirstScreen.js* it gives error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check
>   the render method of `Navigator`.

It seems since i have required *Logout.js* in *FirstScreen.js* ,I am not able to navigate from *Logout.js* to *FirstScreen.js*.

Is there any workaround for that.

Comment: Can we have some code as to how your component are built ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cyclic dependency returning null.

Check here for a longer explaination: [Cyclic dependency returns empty object in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807664/cyclic-dependency-returns-empty-object-in-react-native)