# How to handle dependency cycle in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have two files which import directly from each other like this and it consists of a dependency error.

Saga

```
import { action } from './Action';
```

Action

```
import { saga } from './Saga';
```

I tried adding a new root file and importing functions from that but didn't work either

Root file

```
export * from './sagas/saga';
export * from './actions/action';
```

File 1

```
import { action } from './root file';
```

File 2

```
import { saga } from './root file';
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: Could you please have a look into this - [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807664/cyclic-dependency-returns-empty-object-in-react-native)

Comment: @GreatKT it didn't work for me even with lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the needed function in another file or in the root file then import them from there. Normally if the functions are link the should be group togheter.